# how to scrape anonymously using Scrapy Tor Privoxy & UserAgent? (Windows 10)

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy, tor, privoxy

The answer of this question was quite difficult to find since informations are scattered, and the title of the questions are sometime misleading. The answer below regroup all informations needed in one place.

Answer (score 0):

Your spider should look like.

```
# based on https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html

import scrapy
import requests

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes"

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = [
            'http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/',
            'http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/2/',
        ]
        for url in urls:
            print('\n\nurl:', url)
      ## use one of the yield below

            # middleware will process the request
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse) 

            # check if Tor has changed IP
            #yield scrapy.Request('http://icanhazip.com/', callback=self.is_tor_and_privoxy_used) 


    def parse(self, response):
        page = response.url.split("/")[-2]
        filename = 'quotes-%s.html' % page
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)
        print('\n\nSpider: Start')
        print('Is proxy in response.meta?: ', response.meta)
        print ("user_agent is: ",response.request.headers['User-Agent'])
        print('\n\n Spider: End')
        self.log('Saved file  ---  %s' % filename)


    def is_tor_and_privoxy_used(self, response):
        print('\n\nSpider: Start')
        print("My IP is : " + str(response.body))
        print("Is proxy in response.meta?: ", response.meta)  # not header dispo
        print('\n\nSpider: End')
        self.log('Saved file %s' % filename)
```

**You will also need to add stuff in middleware.py and settings.py .** If you don't know how to do it [this will help you](https://github.com/WiliTest/Anonymous-scrapping-Scrapy-Tor-Privoxy-UserAgent)